# Javascript error not displaying for small screens

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am displaying form errors based on users input and my code is working fine in full screen but when I switch to mobile view the errors stops displaying. The weird part is once the error is produced in full screen. The error comes in mobile view also. But if I directly switch to mobile screen the error is not displayed.

```
<input ng-change="hideAccError()" type="text" name="accountNumber"
                        class="form-control input-style"
                        ng-model="user.accountNumber"
                        required />
                    <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.accountNumber.$touched">
                    
                        <p class="error spacer-top-sm spacer-bottom-xs" ng-show="!!user.errorText && form.$submitted">
                            {{user.errorText}}</p>
                        <p class="error" ng-if="!!user.errorText1 && form.$submitted">
                            <br/>{{user.errorText1}}</p>    
                    </div>
```

`user.errorText` is getting populated so no issue over there. It's just that it is not displaying

Edit : I can see that ng-hide class is getting applied to the text block. But it is getting removed in full screen. And I have no such condition for this

Comment: Switching the browser to a mobile view might not show an accurate representation until you refresh the browser.

Comment: are you hiding the error field in mobile in css?

Comment: @NaveenKashyap no I am not hiding. If this was the case then why it is displaying after it is produced in full screen

Comment: @ChrisG yes tried after refreshing. Same results.

Comment: @ChrisG attached a picture for better understanding